# can you convert MatOfRect to MatOfRect2d?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to get this application to work on my computer. I am using android studios and it is written in java. I have android studio 4.1.1 and am using OpenCV 3.4.10.

There is an error in this line:
Dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, confThreshold, nmsThresh, indices);

Where boxes is MatOfRect and it should be MatOfRect2d but I don’t know how to convert this.

Github link: https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/tree/master/%5BPart%207%5D%20Deep%20Learning%20Face%20Detection

Youtube video of him explaining code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMZsttT57Zo

Answer (score 2):

In the Documentation of OpenCV, Dnn.NMSBoxes(..) accepts **MatOfRect2d** as first parameter [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/dnn/Dnn.html#NMSBoxes(org.opencv.core.MatOfRect2d,org.opencv.core.MatOfFloat,float,float,org.opencv.core.MatOfInt)).
Coming to the Programming part, [Line Number 285](https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/blob/8f0322840822a47990bb317ab5821cf1601f45d0/%5BPart%207%5D%20Deep%20Learning%20Face%20Detection/MainActivity.java#L285) is parametrized with **MatOfRect**. Therefore, It is important to explicitly Type-cast **MatOfRect** to **MatOfRect2d**.

To do so, change the following in the respective line numbers

1. [Line Number 217](https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/blob/8f0322840822a47990bb317ab5821cf1601f45d0/%5BPart%207%5D%20Deep%20Learning%20Face%20Detection/MainActivity.java#L217) change List<Rect> to List<Rect2d>.
2. [Line Number 261](https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/blob/8f0322840822a47990bb317ab5821cf1601f45d0/%5BPart%207%5D%20Deep%20Learning%20Face%20Detection/MainActivity.java#L261) add(new Rect2d(left,top,width,height)).
3. [Line Number 277](https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/blob/8f0322840822a47990bb317ab5821cf1601f45d0/%5BPart%207%5D%20Deep%20Learning%20Face%20Detection/MainActivity.java#L277) Rect2d[] boxesArray = rects.toArray(new Rect2d[0]).
4. [Line Number 285](https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/blob/8f0322840822a47990bb317ab5821cf1601f45d0/%5BPart%207%5D%20Deep%20Learning%20Face%20Detection/MainActivity.java#L279) Replace the line with the following.

> MatOfRect2d bbox = new MatOfRect2d();

> bbox.fromList(rects);

[Documentation to MatOfRect2d](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/javadoc/org/opencv/core/MatOfRect2d.html)

5. Lastly, On [Line Number 293](https://github.com/ivangrov/Android-Deep-Learning-with-OpenCV/blob/8f0322840822a47990bb317ab5821cf1601f45d0/%5BPart%207%5D%20Deep%20Learning%20Face%20Detection/MainActivity.java#L293), replace **Rect** with **Rect2d**

Hopefully, You'll find that the error is vanished.

Hope this Helped!